# SCP File command as non-root user on the server

Tags: shell, root, sudo

I have some files to upload. Usually to edit anything while logged in the server I must precede the command with sudo. That is known.

How do I send a file then as "admin" instead of "root" when I have disabled root login.

`scp path\to\file admin@myaddress.com:/var/www/sitename/public/path/`

**PERMISSION DENIED**

Comment: only /tmp/ is available for SCP as of now

Comment: you should edit your question to include this info AND a description its significance to  your problem (It is not clear to me), Are you OK with putting the files in /tmp ? Also, setting scp transmissions is a well understood task, have you tried searching here on S.O. or on Superuser.com or via google? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, either you should give permissions to the admin user or scp your file to /tmp/ and then `sudo mv /tmp/yourfile /var/www/sitename/public/path/`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sudo option when we are using scp command from local to server.

Each **user will have upload permission to its own folder in home** directory ex. **home/xxxxuser** so use as below:

```
scp file_source_here xxxuser@yourserver:/home/xxxuser/
```

Now you can move file from this folder to your destination.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest these two commands as it works in a bash script.

Move the file to tmp as suggested.

```
scp path\to\file admin@myaddress.com:/tmp
```

Assuming admin user can do sudo. The ssh option -t allow you to do sudo command.

```
ssh -t admin@myaddress.com 'sudo chown root:root /tmp/file && sudo mv /tmp/file /var/www/sitename/public/path/'
```